# How do I fix this C# Windows Services error?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am attempting to check the status of a Windows Service through the console in C#, however it is throwing an error that I'm not sure of the reason for.

Here is the error [image: error]

I have hardcoded "Superfetch" for testing, and this can be seen clearly as a service running in windows.

The Superfetch service is running [image: Superfetch service running].

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: you'll be more likely to get help if you put the text of the code and the exception details into you're issue

Comment: For some bizarre reason, the service name of the "Superfetch" service is "SysMain".  Your code needs to use "SysMain" rather than "Superfetch".

Comment: @ChadNedzlek PNGs were posted with the short code and issue

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't append "solved" to titles here. Posts are shown as solved, when the answer is accepted, which you've already done. Take care the next time!

Comment: @BhargavRao Oh I see, I've joined a cult rather than a community lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the service info detail window to see its original name but not the showing name in the column since sometimes they are not the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hde9d63a(v=vs.110).aspx) which will returns all the services then you can find your service from it.

Even you can use [WaitForStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w52kaf2y(v=vs.110).aspx)
For checking the status of service.